# Spring JMS consumer pull

Tags: spring, jms, jmstemplate

I need to implemt a pulling consumer. 
Most of the examples I see are the producer pushing a message to the consumer; Assuming consumer is always up.
I want the producer to push messages to a queue and the consumer to consume those messages on its own schedule.
My consumer has a off hours calender and cannot process requests during off hours.

How would I configure that in spring.

TIA

Raghu

Answer (score 0):

Use [message driven POJOs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jms.html) and JMS.

Comment: updated link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

Answer (score 0):

The onMessage is a server push, The message is processed as soon as it is delivered to the client. I want the client to decide when it wants to pull the message and process it.